# How do i link a CSS file to a HTML file?

Tags: html, css

I can't link my CSS file to my HTML file.  The link code is as follows:

```
    <link href="/css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

At first i thought my href was wrong, but i tried a lot of other strategies, all of them to be exact.  It might also be my editor.  My editor is Atom.  Please help if possible. the path is shown below:

```
    Users/mac/Documents/mycss.css
```

Comment: Try removing the first `/` if you're not running it on a server/localhost.

Comment: What did you do to bugfix this ?

Comment: Your web server's error log file probably has valuable clues...

Comment: The path is probably wrong, or perhaps you have not added myfile.css, we can't tell as you left that bit out.

Comment: In addition to the server error log, check the network tab of devtools. You'll probably see a 404.

Comment: Write down your directory structure: what is the root of the directory, and where is the HTML file and where the CSS file? Also post all the URLs you tried. Note that, as pointed out, testing locally vs. live, and local server vs. file system may require different approaches.

Comment: Make sure the path to the css file is correct, and that you have provided the correct file name *and* the extension, `.css`

Comment: If not error logs in your server, there should be errors in the developer console of whatever browser you're using. Check the network tab to see where it's looking for the file.

Comment: 1) Does your style sheet file contain errors? 2) are you running locally or online, this will effect the pathing as others have alluded to. 3) What is the full Atom path to the HTML file you're trying to load?

Comment: `/css/mycss.css` is where you're looking but `Users/mac/Documents/mycss.css` is your file path?  Did you not realize that `/css/` is a directory?  If your HTML file is at `Users/mac/Documents/`, you should have a css directory and a path like so: `Users/mac/Documents/css/mycss.css`, but it's impossible to tell if we don't know where your HTML file is located.

Comment: Your `<link>` tag should be inside the `<head> ... </head>` part of your HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Open your CSS file in Google, or whatever browser you use. Copy the code in the search bar, and paste it in the href section. If this doesn't work, you could try implemanting the style element in your head like this:

```
`<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>`
```